# Array slicing in VBA, how can I assign a value to a whole row?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to calculate an array where each row will be a matrix multiplication of earlier row and some matrix. I know that VBA can't handle slicing directly, so I have tried Excel function `index` as below:

```
Dim my_array()

my_array = Range("some.range")
For i = 2 to 100
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(my_array, i, 0) = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult( _ 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(my_array, i-1, 0), Range("some.matrix"))
Next i
```

But it didn't work. So I've tried something simpler:

```
WorksheetFunction.index(my_array, 1, 0) = 1
```

But it didn't work either. Can I even use `Index` slicing to assign a values to `my_array`?

Comment: In a word, no. You can use it to extract data, but not to write it.

Comment: VBA can handle slicing with a custom function. It is not a built-in one.

Answer (score 1):

This is some custom slicing function, that takes the first and the last index of an array to be sliced. See the comments in the `TestMe` function to get how it gets sliced. This is what it does:

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 67)
SliceMe arr, 1, 4
Array(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In general, the `fromIndex` and `toIndex` can be made optional values, to make the function more robust.

```
Sub SliceMe(myArr As Variant, fromIndex As Long, toIndex As Long)

    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim newArr      As Variant
    Dim realIndex   As Variant

    ReDim newArr(toIndex - fromIndex)

    For cnt = fromIndex To toIndex
        newArr(realIndex) = myArr(cnt)
        realIndex = realIndex + 1
    Next cnt

    myArr = newArr

End Sub

Sub TestMe()

    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 67)

    Debug.Print arr(0)              '1
    Debug.Print arr(UBound(arr))    '67

    SliceMe arr, 1, 4

    Debug.Print arr(0)              '2
    Debug.Print arr(UBound(arr))    '5

End Sub
```